# How to re-run oozie failed job

Tags: oozie

I want to know about failed oozie job execution.
Does it run from start or run from the failed point?

I have MR and Pig task to be executed.
If Pig job failed, does it start again from MR job execution?

How to re-run the failed oozie jobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will start from the failed action.

```
oozie job --oozie <oozie_url> -rerun <job_id> -config <job.properties>
```

Add the following property in the `job.properties` if not present already. `-config` parameter is required only if you are updating the `job.properties` file.

```
oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true
```